# 400 error in the code happend when using OpenaI

Tags: prompt, openai-api

I'm trying to make a code using Chat gpt.
The purposes are 1. Crawl my blog 2. Translate it using google api 3. Summarize it using gpt 4. Post it on My bluesky with original url.

But I got a problem. How can I solve this? I already installed npm i openai.

Error: Request failed with status code 400
at createError (C:\Users\node_modules\openai\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
at settle (C:\Users\node_modules\openai\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\node_modules\openai\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:322:11)
at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:525:35)
at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const { Translate } = require('@google-cloud/translate').v2;
const { BskyAgent } = require('@atproto/api');
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require('openai');

dotenv.config();

const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openaiApi = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

const agent = new BskyAgent({ service: 'https://bsky.social/' });
const translate = new Translate({
  projectId: process.env.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID,
  keyFilename: process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS,
});

const summarizeBlog = async (url, summaryLength) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
    const ifra = $('iframe#mainFrame');
    const postUrl = 'https://blog.naver.com' + ifra.attr('src');
    const postResponse = await axios.get(postUrl);
    const postHtml = postResponse.data;
    const post$ = cheerio.load(postHtml);
    
    // Extract the title and contents of the blog post
    const title = post$('div.se-module.se-module-text.se-title-text').text().replace(/\n/g, '');
    const contents = post$('div.se-module.se-module-text').find('span').toArray().map((span) => $(span).text()).join('\n');

    // Translate the text to English
    const [translation] = await translate.translate(contents, 'en');

    // Summarize the translated text using OpenAI's GPT engine
    const completions = await openaiApi.createCompletion({
      engine: 'text-davinci-003',
      prompt: `Summarize this text in ${summaryLength} words or fewer: ${translation}`,
      maxTokens: summaryLength,
      temperature: 0,
      topP: 1,
      frequencyPenalty: 0,
    });
    const summary = completions.choices[0].text;

    return { originalText: contents, translatedText: translation, summary, title };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch and translate the blog');
  }
};

const postToBluesky = async (url, summary, translatedText) => {
  // Login to Bluesky using the bot credentials and post the translated summary
  await agent.login({ identifier: process.env.BLUESKY_BOT_EMAIL, password: process.env.BLUESKY_BOT_PASSWORD });
  const postRecord = {
    $type: 'app.bsky.feed.post',
    text: `Original post: ${url}\n\n${summary}\n\nTranslated from Korean:\n\n${translatedText}`,
    facets: [
      { $type: 'app.bsky.facets.metadata', url },
    ],
    createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
  };
  await agent.post(postRecord);
};

const main = async () => {
  const url = 'https://blog.naver.com/------';
  const summaryLength = 300;
  const { originalText, translatedText, summary, title } = await summarizeBlog(url, summaryLength);
  console.log(`Original Title: ${title}`);
  console.log(`Original Text:\n${originalText}`);
  console.log(`Translated Text:\n${translatedText}`);
  console.log(`Summary:\n${summary}`);
  await postToBluesky(url, summary, translatedText);
};

main();
```